# 301 redirect rewriterule not working in apache for article id=3 and id=39

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I used `RewriteRule` for 301 redirect in Apache server - all URLS working except these two:

1. articles.details.php?recordID=3
2. articles.details.php?recordID=39

```bsh
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} recordID=3
RewriteRule ^articles.details\.php$ /festivals-religious/? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} recordID=39
RewriteRule ^articles.details\.php$ /festivals-traditional/? [L,R=301]
```

Both URLs redirected to: /festivals-religious/.

I think conflict with `recordID=3` and `recoredID=39`, as 3 exists in both URLs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the second `RewriteCond` also matches the first one. One option would be to add a `$` to the end of the first rule, like so:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} recordID=(3)$
RewriteRule ^articles.details.php$ /festivals-religious/? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} recordID=39
RewriteRule ^articles.details.php$ /festivals-traditional/? [L,R=301]
```

The `$` means "the end of this particular query string."